# Custom Hex-Histogram Lables in R's ggplot2

Tags: r

I have a 2D histogram. I'd like to label each bin with some percentages relevant to the data contained within the histogram—but said percentages aren't calculated using the x-y histogram data (they're calculated using the **z** data of the data frame, which is the same length as **x** and **y**).

```
dat = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), z = (11, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13)
hexplot <- ggplot(dat) + 
    geom_hex(aes(x, y), bins=15) + 
    stat_binhex(aes(x, y, label=z), 
                geom="text", bins=15)
hexplot
```

I'm receiving a `geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label` error. I've tried a **lot** of different things, and have learned a lot about how ggplot2's scope works—but I'm still pretty confused when it comes to tackling this problem.

If I move the label outside of aes, I get a length-error. I've tried moving things in and out of aes with various effects, but none of which I understand that well. Furthermore, I can get the labeling to work if I keep it inside of aes and set it to something like "..count.." It *sometimes* works if I set it to **x** or **y**, and never sees *dat* when setting it to something like *dat$y*.

I can fix the length error by throwing in a vector that's the same length as dat$x, but then I get the "geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: label" error. :l This doesn't make much sense to me, because the ..density.., ..count.., ..x.., etc. are all much shorter than that.

All in all, I'm reeaal confused, and would really appreciate some help!

---

Bonus questions:

- What is *aes* exactly, and why does moving things in and out of it change so much?
- What is something like "..count.." and are there other variables/functions like it? (I think *..count..* references the columns from ggplot_build(); there is also ..density..)

Comment: since there are likely to be fewer bins than `z` values, how would you want to deal with multiple labels per bin?  The `..count..` etc variables correspond to columns of `ggplot_build(hexplot)[[1]][[2]]`, the `2` referring to the `stat_binhex` geom

Comment: @bunk I've been looking for a way to do two things: First, figure out how to use a geom_text to label the histogram correctly (right now, I'm trying to use the (x,y) values from ggplot_build to be the (x,y) values of geom_text—or, as it is now, annotate). Second, figure out a way to extract which data is being put into which bin. This way I can calculate these averages and put them into another vector, using annotate or something.

Comment: @bunk Do you have any ideas?

Comment: well, getting the x,y values for the center of the bins is easy enough doing as you say with ggplot_build.  But, it you are doing something fancy with the values in each bin, I would do it before plotting, using `hexbin::hcell2xy`

Comment: @bunk  hexbin::hcell2xy actually makes it super easy to get the bin centers (ggplot_build was off, for some reason). The fancy stuff isn't w/ the data inside of the bins, though. It's with the data *associated* to each bin, outside of the scope of the histogram. :(

Comment: yea, ggplot does a little housekeeping, https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-binhex.r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it! I would type expletives, capital letters, and lots of exclamation marks, but since that is not site-appropriate—just know that I am pretty excited.

The key is to pass a third column into `ggplot2` as **z** and use `stat_summary_hex`, which has allows a function argument, on **z**.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100000, 0, 5), y = rnorm(100000, 0, 5), z = rnorm(100000, 42, 42))

hexHist = ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, z = z)) + 
    stat_binhex(bins = 10) +
    stat_summary_hex(aes(label=..value..), bins = 10,
                     fun = function(z) {
                         (round(sum(z)/length(z), 0))
                     },
                     geom = "text")
```

[image: 2D hexagonal density histogram with the mean of a third variable within the bin superimposed over it]

There's this issue where some numbers are far away from their tiles and some tiles aren't plotted. I don't understand why this happens, but I've been told it's an issue with ggplot2.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
plot <- ggplot(dat,aes(x,y,label=z))+geom_hex()+geom_text()
```

Comment: Close! (Closer than I ever got). I'm using a set number of bins (smaller than the default). How could I go about labeling it appropriately (the length of the *z* has to be the same as *x* and *y*, apparently, but *x* and *y* are binned)?

Comment: `plot <- ggplot(dat,aes(x,y,label=z))+geom_hex(bins=15)+geom_text()
` ?

Comment: That won't work, unfortunately. It'll give me the correct number of bins, but it doesn't appropriately scale the number of labels. (So, while they're 15*15 bins, there will be a label for every data point, which is around 10,000 :D)